# How to parse JSON graph with special character annotation using Json Jackson?

Tags: android, jackson, dollar-sign

here is my graph `"seriesType": {
"code": "83001",
"$": "Série"
}`
How do I parse this json with json jackson? I am not able to because the dollar sign is generating an error.

i tried this

```
public Dollar serieType;
public class Dollar {
public int code;
public String $;
```

}

```
// is is the input stream
jp = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(is);
        serieType = objectMapper.readValue(jp, Dollar.class);
 strBuffer.append("serieType: " + dollar.$ + "\n");
```

//  It's some how what i tried, i am sure that the problem is caused by the dollar sign.

I tried to get a value like this `String s=tvseries.serieType.$` and this is the stacktrace `01-02 10:48:03.905: W/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
01-02 10:48:04.623: W/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{5b799e28 com.test.jackson/.MainAlloCine}
01-02 10:48:07.886: W/System.err(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at com.test.jackson.MainAlloCine.onCreate(MainAlloCine.java:49)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 10:48:07.895: W/System.err(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-02 10:48:07.905: W/System.err(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-02 10:48:07.905: W/System.err(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-02 10:48:07.905: W/System.err(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `@JsonProperty` annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("$")
public String value; // or whatever name you want
```

assuming your problem is with Java compiler which does not let you use dollar character in names (because it uses it internally how inner class names etc).

EDIT:

Looking at exact JSON, the other potential issue is simple: your structure does not match. You need one wrapper object:

```
public class DollarWrapper {
    public Dollar seriesType
}
```

and bind to that. But as usual, this extra level of wrapping seems... well, extra. Why does service insist on adding it?

Comment: So what is the problem? Exception, missing value or what? Btw, your structure is wrong: it has to match.

Comment: the application crashs when he read "$", i am sure 100% my structure is correct, i always use json and parsers. This is the graph you can take a look, [graph](http://api.allocine.fr/rest/v3/tvseries?partner=YW5kcm9pZC12M3M&code=223&profile=large&mediafmt=mp4-lc&format=json&striptags=synopsis,synopsisshort)

Comment: Crash? If so, you should find out stack trace: otherwise it's pretty hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Mr Staxman, happy new year, iedited my answer, you can see the stack trace there.

Comment: this is a [link](http://www.4shared.com/zip/gTwe-EcG/NewJackson.html) for my project if wanna take a look, thanks,